# MAMP localhost redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, localhost, mamp

I develop sites in MAMP on my local network so I've decided to setup port-forwarding to open up my external network and allow HTTP traffic to go directly to my localhost.

Everything is working fine and I can access my MAMP folder using my static IP but,

All my WordPress installs are using `http://localhost` as the prefix and the images/css/js aren't working when accessing the site outside the local network.

Is there anyway I can tell MAMP to redirect ALL localhost traffic to my static IP? I was modifying the vhosts file but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Change the `Site URL` in your WordPress admin to `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` instead of `http://localhost`?

Comment: Yeah I did that, but I have 20+ sites in there and it won't work for images/posts that are already uploaded unless I go into the database table and do a search and replace.

Comment: Why would you have hardcoded links to `http://localhost` in the database?

Comment: The sites were all developed using http://localhost as the SITE url so when you upload an image in a post/page wordpress uses that URL when it makes its absolute URLS.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't a direct answer to your question, but I've had the same issue and have successfully used this plugin to migrate sites from localhost to the production domain. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/.

Note: I've never had any issues, but please backup your db first. Better safe than sorry.